# Adobe PhoneGap Build Disabling Overscroll

Tags: cordova, adobe

Using PhoneGap through Adobe's build.phonegap.com (PhoneGap 3.1.0) I can't stop the overscroll bounce behavior. Here is my basic config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "----------------"
    version     = "0.3.0" >

    <name>-----------</name>

    <description>
    </description>

    <author href="http://www.---------.com" email="info@---------.com">---------</author>

    <gap:platform name="ios" />

    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>

</widget>
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried, `<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />` with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Its working fine for me in IOS using phonegap version 2.9.0 to 3.3.0. You have to include both preferences.

Answer (score 0):

@Suhas: Adobe support told me the same thing. Putting both lines,

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
```

seems to do the trick. On an iOS device at least...